# Why doesn't the xbacklight command work in rc.local?

Tags: 12.04, scripts, bashrc

When I execute the command `xbacklight -set 10` in my terminal the brightness is set to 0.1 as it should.

But when I use this command in my `rc.local`-file, then it is not executed upon start -- because the brightness is not changed. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use `rc.local` for such things. `rc.local` is executed after each runlevel, when the GUI is not yet loaded.

## At user login (doesn't matter which desktop environment)

So, create a file called `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/98xbacklight` with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
xbacklight -display :0 -set 10
```

Now, evertime a new graphical session starts this script will be executed.

## At lightdm start

Maybe you want the backlight to the dimmed **before** you login. To do this add a line in your `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` in the `[SeatDefaults]` part:

```
display-setup-script=/etc/X11/Xsession.d/98xbacklight
```

But, for this the script has to be executable, so set the rights as follows:

```
chmod 755 /etc/X11/Xsession.d/98xbacklight
```